# How to add a span around the first part of text in a div

Tags: jquery, css, identify

I'm trying to wrap a span around the first part of a plain text in a div and style it with a different font-color and font size and have a line-break after it. The problem is, that it's a plain text in which I can't add any custom code in the backend, so I have to find a trick to do the job.

It's a plain text input field in a CMS and this is the result in the frontend:

---

```
Next date: 12.09.-25.09.2019. In this course you can learn how to...
```

---

It's the date-part, which I want to highlight...

Now I have several ideas to do the trick:

### 1. Set the date in [ ], and identify it via jQuery like:

```
[Next date: 12.09.-25.09.2019] In this course you can learn how to...
```

---

So everything in between the brackets should be red for example

2. To count the first 28 characters, and make them appear red in the
   frontend, so I have to keep the date structure always the same,
   which is possible, but not so handy

### 3. To insert ### after the date/part I want to highlight...

```
Next date: 12.09.-25.09.2019 ### In this course you can learn how to...
```

---

... and tell jquery to find everything before the ### and wrap a span around. The ### should disappear of course, when their job is done :-)

Important to know... there will be multiple different dates on one site, so maybe the third solution would work best, so I could parse the entire site and search for the ### to edit everything that's before it, in every instance... so it wouldn't matter what it says before those hashtags... it would also be nice to add a line-break after the ### so that the following text starts in a new line...

this is the given code:

```
<div id="cc-m-1" class="j-module n j-text ">
Next date: 12.09.-25.09.2019 In this course you can learn how to...
</div>

<div id="cc-m-1" class="j-module n j-text ">
Next date: 26.09.-05.10.2019 This is another course for you...
</div>
```

Hope you get the idea, and someone can assist me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello and welcome! Are you asking how to write the code for your solutions? If so - where are your attempt(s)? OR are you asking what we would do? if so - please modify your question after reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is this date format though? `12.09.-25.09.2019` -- if the date will always look like that or will always be a fixed width *and* the "date" string will resolve as a valid `Date`, I would just read in the desired number of characters from the text in your div (buffer style) and when you get a valid `Date` back, use the current position in the buffer and read in the previous number of characters needed to wrap and style as needed.

Comment: Just a note that all id's on a page should be unique (id="cc-m-1" appears twice in your example)

Comment: I tryed different solutions from stackoverflow, but couldn't make it work with none of the attempts. I've tried for art least 3 hours with different attempts :-( So I decided to ask the experts since I know a bit of HTML and CSS, but hardly about jQuery...

Comment: I know the thing with the unique ID's, but this is original code from JIMDO, which is a well known CMS over here in Germany, and that's their code :-)

Comment: The date-format can slightly change, maybe there is a course which is only on one day, so the string would be shorter... that's why I guessed, that the last solution would work best, in order to be able to insert no matter what before those ### or is this completely stupid? I'm no coder, this was just an idea :-)

Answer (score 1):

Without a better sample of your data, it's tough to handle all the quirks, but this should get you started. Good luck!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".j-module").each(function() {
    styleDiv($(this).attr("id"));
  });
});

function isDate(dt) {
  var date = new Date(dt.replace(".", "-"));
  return (date instanceof Date);
}

function styleDiv(id) {
  var alltext = $("#" + id);
  var chunks = new Array();
  chunks = $("#" + id).text().split(" ");
  var texttobold = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
    var dateFinder = chunks[i];
    texttobold = texttobold += " " + dateFinder;
    if (dateFinder.length == 10 && isDate(dateFinder)) {
      var outpt = "<span class='boldtext'>" + texttobold + "</span>";
      alltext.html(alltext.text().replace(texttobold.trim(), outpt));
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.boldtext {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cc-m-1" class="j-module n j-text">
  Next date: 25.09.2019 In this course you can learn how to...
</div>

<div id="cc-m-2" class="j-module n j-text">
  Your favorite date: 21.12.2020 In this course you can learn how to...
</div>

<div id="cc-m-3" class="j-module n j-text">
  Next date: 04.09.2019 In this course you can learn how to...
</div>
```

Edited to expand the required range of text to style.

Comment: hi mjw, thanks for your support... I gave it a try but unfortunately that didn't work in my case. as I told you it's a CMS in which I have to deal with the given code. One part of it is, that it uses the id="cc-m-1" multiple times on one page... that's something I can't change. Your solution seems to deal with the "date" format although I have to admit, that I don't understand much about the code you provided... I think a better solution is on of the other ideas I privided... to parse the entire site and make jQuery find strings between [ ] brackets and to assign a class to them...

Comment: I even want to enclose more into the bold status, like: [Next date: 12.09.-25.09.2019] or it could even look like [Next date: 25.09.2019]... so everything inbetween the brackets should be wrapped by a span...

Comment: Here's the thing about the IDs. they should *absolutely* be unique on your pages. If they're not, you shouldn't be using IDs for jQuery selectors, and in this case we'll need to see the full HTML of the page in question, not just a few div elements you wish to style. It is reasonable to select elements for styling by class, or tag name...and parse them as a set based on some logic that checks the data...but without seeing all the markup I can't do that for you. SO is not a site for free software solutions. It is for *helping* developers solve problems with *code you're writing* - good luck